# What is this aircraft and its submarine?

Tags: military, aviation-history, aircraft-identification

[image: Submarine aircraft carrier]

I got this picture from an anonymous source and I'm curious to learn more about its mission and I want to know if it's a genuine picture. It happens to be a submarine aircraft carrier.

Comment: The Japanese, during WWII, actually built three examples of a sub that could launch and recover a float version of one of their fighter-bombers.  One saw actual service, but was scuttled off South America when Japan surrendered.

Comment: yes it was I-400 class submarine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a joke. It was first posted – [at least as far back as 2001](http://web.archive.org/web/20010209111345/http://www.skyhawk.org/aus_sub.htm) – on skyhawk.org with the caption:

> The Royal Australian Navy Skyhawk, being an all-purpose aircraft, was the subject of a 1970s experimental sea trial of an A-4 on board a Royal Australian Navy submarine. There was no objection from the aviators to operating the Skyhawk from the somewhat limited deck space of the submarine. A problem with the Skyhawk's turbine cavitating while underway submerged was overcome. The diesel catapult worked just fine. However, the experiment was abandoned when the submarine's XO objected to the jet blast burning the paintwork off the sail.

More here:

- http://skyhawk.org/article/humor-page-two (the current live version)
- http://warbirdsnews.com/warbirds-news/fun-facts/1965-mig-flies-bridge-a-4-submarine-fake-real.html
- https://www.airliners.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=1007945

Anyway, the plane is a [McDonnell Douglas A-4G Skyhawk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_A-4G_Skyhawk), the sub is reportedly an [Oberon-class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oberon-class_submarine), and the helicopter is a [Westland Wessex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westland_Wessex).

Comment: Thankyou for your efforts..in finding the info about it..well appreciated :)